# Kettle join two datastream for a table output

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle, spoon

How is the method for join 2 data stream from 2 sources.

I have 2 MSSQL tables and i need to pull the data to a MySQL table BUT i dont have enough fields in MSSQL stream to fit the MySQL table not null fields.. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your next question, which I just answered, you found the right answer. Just fill in the null fields with constant defaults (Add Constants).